# Accept cookies using cURL?

Tags: php, cookies, curl, file-get-contents

I've been trying to get the contents of a webpage using cURL, but have trouble getting cURL to accept cookies.
For example, on Target.com, when I cURL it, it still says that I have to enable cookies.

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.target.com/p/Acer-Gateway-15-6-Laptop-PC-NV57H77u-with-320GB-Hard-Drive-4GB-Memory-Black/-/A-13996190#?lnk=sc_qi_detailbutton";
$ch = curl_init();    // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // times out after 4s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"); 
$cookie_file = "cookie1.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process
curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
```

What else am I missing?
The cookie1.txt file is 077 permission, by the way.

Comment: 077 is an invalid permission, this means the owner (probably apache) has no access. Try setting it to 644 as it's only a file.

Comment: @MikePurcell Why are you posting it as a comment? Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Truth: Wasn't sure if it was a type or not.

Answer (score 4):

077 is an malformed permission setting, this means the owner (probably apache) has no access. Try setting it to 644 (owner has read/write) as it's only a file.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out your issue?